# Deprecated save and load methods in Abstract Model

Tags: magento2, model, magento-2.0, magento-2.0.5, deprecated

I see that in the develop branch of the Magento 2 repo the methods [`load`](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.0/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/Model/AbstractModel.php#L527) and [`save`](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.0/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/Model/AbstractModel.php#L627) from `Magento\Framework\Model\AbstractModel` class are deprecated.
But there are a gazillion classes in the core that extend this class and use `save` and `load`.
When creating my own module for the CRUD part of my entities I follow the same guidelines as a core module does.
But since these methods are deprecated I would rather be prepared for the future.
What should I use instead of them? Or I should extend something else?

Comment: Are these methods are deprecated now?

Comment: If, by now you mean 2.3, yes they are: https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.3/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/Model/AbstractModel.php#L531

Answer (score 38, accepted):

You should use Module Service Contract.

For example for product you should use [ProductRepositoryInterface](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.3/app/code/Magento/Catalog/Api/ProductRepositoryInterface.php)

```
<?php
/**
 *
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */

namespace Magento\Catalog\Api;

/**
 * @api
 * @since 100.0.2
 */
interface ProductRepositoryInterface
{
    /**
     * Create product
     *
     * @param \Magento\Catalog\Api\Data\ProductInterface $product
     * @param bool $saveOptions
     * @return \Magento\Catalog\Api\Data\ProductInterface
     * @throws \Magento\Framework\Exception\InputException
     * @throws \Magento\Framework\Exception\StateException
     * @throws \Magento\Framework\Exception\CouldNotSaveException
     */
    public function save(\Magento\Catalog\Api\Data\ProductInterface $product, $saveOptions = false);

    /**
     * Get info about product by product SKU
     *
     * @param string $sku
     * @param bool $editMode
     * @param int|null $storeId
     * @param bool $forceReload
     * @return \Magento\Catalog\Api\Data\ProductInterface
     * @throws \Magento\Framework\Exception\NoSuchEntityException
     */
    public function get($sku, $editMode = false, $storeId = null, $forceReload = false);

    /**
     * Get info about product by product id
     *
     * @param int $productId
     * @param bool $editMode
     * @param int|null $storeId
     * @param bool $forceReload
     * @return \Magento\Catalog\Api\Data\ProductInterface
     * @throws \Magento\Framework\Exception\NoSuchEntityException
     */
    public function getById($productId, $editMode = false, $storeId = null, $forceReload = false);

    /**
     * Delete product
     *
     * @param \Magento\Catalog\Api\Data\ProductInterface $product
     * @return bool Will returned True if deleted
     * @throws \Magento\Framework\Exception\StateException
     */
    public function delete(\Magento\Catalog\Api\Data\ProductInterface $product);

    /**
     * @param string $sku
     * @return bool Will returned True if deleted
     * @throws \Magento\Framework\Exception\NoSuchEntityException
     * @throws \Magento\Framework\Exception\StateException
     */
    public function deleteById($sku);

    /**
     * Get product list
     *
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Api\SearchCriteriaInterface $searchCriteria
     * @return \Magento\Catalog\Api\Data\ProductSearchResultsInterface
     */
    public function getList(\Magento\Framework\Api\SearchCriteriaInterface $searchCriteria);
}
```

If Module Service Contract is not available you can use ResourceModel to save entities.

Comment: I see. This makes sense. But can you confirm that all the core CRUD modules will have service contracts at one point?

Comment: In long term perspective all modules will have Service Contract. It's our goal. (but it's my personal opinion, i do not represent officially Magento ;)

Comment: good enough for me. :)

Comment: I see that the implementation of `ProductRepositoryInterface` still uses `load` in the methods `get` and `getById`. Should I use the resource model for my module instead of this `load` method?

Comment: yes, for your module better to use ResourceModel in your Module SL

Comment: can you please give some example code for how we can use ResourceModel

Comment: As far as my understanding goes this is not applicable to custom tables

Comment: Do you have any examples? I looked at the official review and newsletter modules, and they are calling "save" directly. I cannot find an example of using ResourceModel. I have it defined for my module, but how to use it?

Comment: Do you have any examples of how specifically to use Resource Model i feel it would really improve your answer

Comment: As for question about usage of resource model, which also should work for any models, also custom ones: `$modelObject->setData($data); $resourceModelObject->save($modelObject);` So, it works exactly the same like using resource model in M1. For delete: `$resourceModelObject->delete($modelObject);` and for loading `$resourceModelObject->load($modelObject, $value, $idFieldName);` where id field is optional unless you want to load the model with field other than it's ID (entity_id usually);

Answer (score 25):

From what I understood, what is going to happen is Magento is going to switch to hydrators with `extract()` and `hydrate()` methods.

This link used to work but it seems like Magento team rolled it back: https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/develop/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/Model/Entity/EntityHydrator.php

You can find the history of the commit here though: https://github.com/magento/magento2/tree/09132da06e18dde0f90aabfc962db2bc19b64f3c/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/Model/Entity

The important files are:

- `EntityHydrator.php`
- `EntityMetadata.php`
- `HydratorInterface.php`
- `MetadataPool.php`

I also suggest you check out the files under the `Action` folder as well as the `Sequence` files.

From what I understood (I may be totally wrong here):

- the files under the `Action` folder are CRUD actions
- the `Sequence` files are iterators ?

That was a conversation that happened a while ago (was it Alan Storm who mentionned it ? can't remember) so I'm not sure if Magento team is still going that way.

**Update**

From my research, the internal Magento ticket regarding this change is MAGETWO-50676, here are the related commits I managed to find:

- https://github.com/magento/magento2/commit/d57c81ced2419cde9d8af2f55062a783ec6a7789
- https://github.com/magento/magento2/commit/35d2da47a20e978c1cb970db79ee4ea60de56353
- https://github.com/magento/magento2/commit/074b3abc6803454542ff0527110e575309c42466

There's probably more TBH but I don't feel like browsing the entire repo for commit messages ^^

If you're not familiar with hydrators, I suggest you check that link out: http://www.webconsults.eu/blog/entry/108-What_is_a_Hydrator_in_Zend_Framework_2

**Update from 2.1**

Magento is now using the `EntityManager` class to replace the inheritance you can find more information here: [Magento 2.1: using the entity manager](https://magento.stackexchange.com/q/127325/2380)

Comment: Ok. Nice theory. But I could use an example from the core. I'm sorry, but my magento skills resume to copy/paste/replace :). You mentioned Action and Sequence files. Can you be more specific?

Comment: @Marius unfortunately that's all I know. I can't remember where I got that info from but the plan at that time was to use this particular commit: https://github.com/magento/magento2/tree/09132da06e18dde0f90aabfc962db2bc19b64f3c/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/Model/Entity to implement the switch from `load()/save()` to hydrators. I assume `Sequences` work like iterators and `Actions` are CRUD actions

Comment: you find an example in the current cms block resource model load method: https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/develop/app/code/Magento/Cms/Model/ResourceModel/Block.php#L137 It uses the entityManager->load https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/develop/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/EntityManager/EntityManager.php#L61 which executes a ReadMain operation (I think) https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/develop/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/EntityManager/Operation/Read/ReadMain.php#L64 which hydrates the skeleton entity with the loaded entity data (nice move from Magento ;))

Answer (score 6):

An alternative to Magento 2 Deprecated Load Method is the resource model load method.

```
public funtion getCustomer($id)
{
   $customerModel = $this->customerFactory->create();
   $this->customerResource->load($customerModel, $id);
   $customerModel->getEmail();  
}
```

here the first parameter is the model object and the second parameter is id you want to load.

An alternative to Magento 2 Deprecated Save Method is the resource model save method.

```
public funtion save($taskData)
{
   $taskModel = $this->taskFactory->create()->setData($taskData);
   $this->resource->save($taskModel);
}
```

save method accepts only one parameter that is your model object.

Answer (score 4):

See description in the class code https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.1/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/Model/AbstractModel.php#L626

Comment: Any idea when `load` `save` and `delete` are going to go away?

Comment: They will stay for 2-3 minor releases

Comment: and yet here we are.