# Magento 2 : How to load quote by quote id

Tags: magento2, magento-2.0, quote

How can I **load quote in magento 2 by quote id** ?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

you can inject in your class an instance of `\Magento\Quote\Model\QuoteFactory`.

```
protected $quoteFactory;

public function __construct(
    ...
    \Magento\Quote\Model\QuoteFactory $quoteFactory,
    ....
) {
    ....
    $this->quoteFactory = $quoteFactory;
    ....
}
```

Then you can use:

```
$quote = $this->quoteFactory->create()->load($quoteId);
```

This should work for now, 
but soon, the [`load` method is going to go away](https://magento.stackexchange.com/q/114929/146) and you need to use a service contract.
So you can use `\Magento\Quote\Api\CartRepositoryInterface`.
Same as above, inject an instance of this class in your class:

```
protected $quoteRepository;

public function __construct(
    ...
    \Magento\Quote\Api\CartRepositoryInterface $quoteRepository,
    ....
) {
    ....
    $this->quoteRepository = $quoteRepository;
    ....
}
```

and use this:

```
$this->quoteRepository->get($quoteId);
```

If you want to see how the code looks like, the implementation for `\Magento\Quote\Api\CartRepositoryInterface` is `\Magento\Quote\Model\QuoteRepository`

Comment: Hi @Marius, will this work in case of multiple store views as well?

Comment: I think it will work

Comment: This is deprecated, how does it work now?

Comment: @Black. The second approach is still valid. The one with `CartRepositoryInterface`

Answer (score 17):

First you need to inject a `\Magento\Quote\Model\QuoteFactory` in your class constructor:

```
protected $_quoteFactory;

public function __construct(
    ...
    \Magento\Quote\Model\QuoteFactory $quoteFactory
) {
    $this->_quoteFactory = $quoteFactory;
    parent::__construct(...);
}
```

Then in your class you can do:

```
$this->_quoteFactory->create()->loadByIdWithoutStore($quoteId);
```

On a side note you can also use the following methods to load a quote:

- `loadActive($quoteId)` where it loads corresponding active quote (where `is_active` = 1)
- `loadByCustomerId($customerId)` where it load the active quote corresponding to the customer id.

NB: you can also use the object manager directly to do it but **it is not recommended**:

```
$this->_objectManager->create('Magento\Quote\Model\Quote')->loadByIdWithoutStore($quoteId);
```

Comment: `\Magento\Quote\Model\Quote` is a non-injectable class. I mean you can inject it, but it's not the best idea to do so. If you inject this class in 2 other classes you will get it as a singleton in the DI container and if you call `load` once in one of the classes, you will have it "loaded" in your other class also. Most probably you don't want that. Use factories instead.

Comment: @Marius here's what happens when you're working on M1 and M2 projects at the same time. You tend to mix up everything. Thanks for the enlight and +1 for your solution, definitely the right way to go with service contracts

Comment: Instead of `$this->_objectManager->get('Magento\Quote\Model\QuoteFactory')->create()->loadByIdWithoutStore($quoteId);` you can use `$this->_objectManager->create('Magento\Quote\Model\Quote')->loadByIdWithoutStore($quoteId);` For the same reason stated above. calling `get` on the OM will result in a singleton.

Comment: @Marius I find that `get` vs `create` is more obvious than the use of singletons of M1 but I still tend to misuse them

Comment: Don't worry. Been there, done that. :)

Comment: `loadByCustomerId` does not seem to work though: `Invalid method Magento\Quote\Model\Quote::loadByCustomerId`

Answer (score 0):

I recommend the following method

```
use Psr\Log\LoggerInterface;
use Magento\Quote\Api\CartRepositoryInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Exception\NoSuchEntityException;
use Magento\Quote\Api\Data\CartInterface;

class MyClass
{
    /**
     * @var CartRepositoryInterface
     */
    public $quoteRepository;

    /**
     * @var LoggerInterface
     */
    public $logger;
        public function __construct(
        CartRepositoryInterface $quoteRepository,
        LoggerInterface $logger
    ) {
        $this->quoteRepository = $quoteRepository;
        $this->logger = $logger;
    }

    /**
     * Get Quote By Id    
     * @param int $quoteId
     * @return CartInterface|null
     */
    public function getQuoteById(int $quoteId): ?CartInterface
    {
        $quote = null;
        try {
            $quote = $this->quoteRepository->get($quoteId);
        } catch (NoSuchEntityException $e) {
            $this->logger->error(
                'Quote does not exist'.,
                [$e->getMessage()]
            );
        }
        return $quote;
    }
}
```