# How to change Product price of a Cart? [SOLVED]

Tags: magento2, product, orders, cart, rest-api

I created an order using Rest Api and i want to change the Produt Price from a Cart.
I tried this:

But didn't work, this line: *$quote = $this->quoteFactory->create()->load($resultQuote->quote_id);* returns null. What could be? Any help is appreciated.

```
 $quote = $this->quoteFactory->create()->load($resultQuote->quote_id);
 $items = $quote->getItemsCollection();

 foreach ($items as $item) {

    $item->setPrice(999);
    $item->setRowTotal(999);
    $item->setCustomPrice(999);
    $item->setOriginalPrice(999);
    $item->setOriginalCustomPrice(999);
    $item->getProduct()->setIsSuperMode(true);
    $item->save();
    $quote->save();
 }

 $quote->setTotalsCollectedFlag(false)->collectTotals();
 $quote->save();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this following this tutorial [Magento 2 : How to load quote by quote id](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/115129/magento-2-how-to-load-quote-by-quote-id)

looks like the **load** function is depreciated and doesn't works anymore.