# Update table use where codition(CRUD) - Magento 2

Tags: magento2, database, table, crud

I need to update particular field in table using CRUD operation of Magento.

I have tried below for insert new record **it is working**

```
$this->_cancelFactory->create()->setData(array('cancel_status'=>'Review'))->save();
```

I have tried below for update particular row but it does not work

```
$this->_cancelFactory->create()->setData(array('cancel_status'=>'Canceled'))->where(array('order_id'=>$oid))->save();
```

What is the right way to update table?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$cancelId = 5;//id for entry to update
$cancel = $this->_cancelFactory->create();
$cancel->load($cancelId);
$cancel->setCancelStatus('Review');
$cancel->save();
```

But as explained in the answers in here: [Deprecated save and load methods in Abstract Model](https://magento.stackexchange.com/q/114929/146), `load` and `save` are deprecated. You should create service contracts for your module.