# programatically cancel the order using order id - Magento 2

Tags: magento2, orders, magento-2.0, order-status

My requirement is programatically change the order status to **Canceled** by **using order id**.

How to achieve this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Update table use where codition(CRUD) - Magento 2](http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/115240/update-table-use-where-coditioncrud-magento-2)

Comment: that question is asked by me, before that I am playing with custom table with CRUD. I think that one is query related, that one is useful for all operations of update particular field. Now, I am looking for change default order status right now.

Comment: yes I retracted my close vote once I noticed that and upvoted your question ;)

Comment: Check link, https://www.rakeshjesadiya.com/how-to-cancel-order-programmatically-in-magento-2/

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Even though using the `OrderFactory` would work, [`save` and `load` methods are deprecated soon](https://magento.stackexchange.com/q/114929/146), you should use service contracts instead.

So you can use `Magento/Sales/Api/OrderManagementInterface`:

First inject an instance in your class constructor:

```
protected $orderManagement;

public function __construct(
    ...
    \Magento\Sales\Api\OrderManagementInterface $orderManagement,
    ....
) {
    ....
    $this->orderManagement = $orderManagement;
    ....
}
```

Then use the following:

```
$this->orderManagement->cancel($orderId);
```

Comment: Hi @Raphael http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/164002/magento-2-how-to-refund-or-cancel-paypal-order

Comment: Please check here it works perfect for me  
http://magentocodes.blogspot.in/2017/10/how-to-cancel-order-programatically-in.html

Answer (score 3):

use `\Magento\Sales\Model\OrderFactory` by injecting in the constructor, like below : to cancel the order programmatically

```
protected $_orderFactory;

public function __construct(
     \Magento\Sales\Model\OrderFactory $orderFactory
){
$this->_orderFactory = $orderFactory;
}

public function execute()
{
    $orderId = '1234543343'; // your order id
    $order = $this->_orderFactory->create()->load($orderId);
    $order->cancel()->save();   
}
```

Comment: thanks, it worked but load() save() are deprecated soon as per @Raphael +1 from me :-)

Answer (score -1):

I tried below solution and it works perfect

http://magentocodes.blogspot.com/2017/10/how-to-cancel-order-programatically-in.html