# Magento 2: How to Refund, Cancel & Re-Authorize Paypal Order Programmatically

Tags: magento2, custom, payment-methods, paypal, magento2.1.5

How to use below function for already Ordered by Paypal

**magento\vendor\magento\module-paypal\Model\Express.php**

```
refund()
void()
```

First need to load the Order then will get the payment

```
$orderId = 1;

$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$order = $objectManager->create('\Magento\Sales\Model\Order')->load($orderId); 
$order->getPayment()
```

After Refund & Cancel Order from Paypal need to Update Order Status accordingly & Notify Customer.

**Re-Authorization**: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/paypal-payments-standard/integration-guide/authcapture/ Paypal holds payment for 29 days. How can I extend it?