# Magento 2 Update record/table with where clause

Tags: magento2, database, sql, query

How can I update record with **multiple where clause**? I know below method to update record with single where condition.  I tried to used ***addFieldToFilter()***
but not succeeded.

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$order_ = $objectManager->create('<ext_name>\<module_name>\Model\OrderSaleslist')
                                       ->load($orderId); 
$order_->setSellerOrderConfirm("dispatched");
$order_->save();
```

I want to apply below query.

***Update ordersaleslist set seller_order_confirm = 'dispatched', payment_mode = 'COD' where order_id = 1 and product_id = 20 and (status !='' OR dispatched_status!='');***

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

you can apply multiple **where** with **AND** logic

e.g

```
    $collections = $this->_yourFactory->create()->getCollection()
                 ->addFieldToFilter('order_id', array('eq' => '1'))
                 ->addFieldToFilter('product_id', array('eq' => '20'));
    foreach($collections as $item)
    {
        $item->setSellerOrderConfirm('dispatched');
        $item->setPaymentMode('COD');
    }
    $collection->save();
```

object manager is not recommended. load and save methods are deprecated for best practice you should use service contracts. for more info refer this [link](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/115242/36463)

Answer (score 1):

```
 <?php
namespace Vendor\MyModule\Model;

use Magento\Framework\Model\AbstractModel;
 class Products extends AbstractModel
    {
        protected function _construct()
        {

            $this->_init(\Vendor\MyModule\Model\ResourceModel\Products::class);
        }
        public function setProduct($newProductId){    
           $collection = $this->getCollection()->addFieldToFilter('product_id', $);
           $collection->getFirstItem()->setData('product_id',$newProductId)->save();
        }
}
```

I update product Id using collection in magento2 I called setProduct() from the controller.

main logic to update is

```
 $collection = $this->getCollection()->addFieldToFilter('product_id', $);
               $collection->getFirstItem()->setData('product_id',$newProductId)->save();
```

Answer (score 0):

You have used two time

`$order_->setSellerOrderConfirm("dispatched")->setSellerOrderConfirm("dispatched")`

just use once `$order_->setSellerOrderConfirm("dispatched")`.

if not work then you can use like this,

```
$order_->addFieldToFilter('order_id ', array('eq' => 1));
```

May be it will help you.

Comment: Thanks, I am not looking for this, Please check query. **I want multiple where condition for update record**

Comment: you can use `addFieldToFilter` as many time as you want.