# Can not get model by id

Tags: event-observer, magento-2.1.7

I have the following Observer event that is called after the product is saved.

> Subscribers

is a custom model

```
<?php

namespace Namespace\Modulename\Observer;

use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;
use Namespace\Modulename\Model\SubscribersFactory;

class Productsaveafter implements ObserverInterface {

    public function __construct(
    SubscribersFactory $modelSubscribersFactory
    ) {
        $this->_modelSubscribersFactory = $modelSubscribersFactory;
    }

    public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer) {
        $_product = $observer->getProduct();  // you will get product object
        $_sku = $_product->getSku(); // for sku
        $subscriber_product_id = $_product->getId();//gives '2'
        $subscriber = $this->_modelSubscribersFactory->create()->getCollection();//This is working

        $subscriber = $this->_modelSubscribersFactory->create()->load(2);//This is not working

    }

}
```

I can not figure out why ths 'load' function is not working.

Comment: @Priyank, I will look into that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not use `load()` as per Magento Best Practice. Please implement [Service Contracts](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/115269/how-to-implement-service-contract-for-a-custom-module-in-magento-2) for your Module and use `getById($id)` method