# difference between Model\ProductRepository and Api\ProductRepositoryInterface

Tags: magento2, catalog

What is the difference between using `\Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductRepository` and `\Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductRepositoryInterface`?

Which one is better and recommended to use?

Comment: API folder used for handle Interface related classes,contains any PHP classes exposed to the api & Model use to handle module related logic & Datamodel (CRUD)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not 100% deep knowledge of this.

But i am pretty sure that  you should use

> **\Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductRepositoryInterface**

As it can use for both api and model layer

See the magento document:

http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1//extension-dev-guide/service-contracts/design-patterns.html#service-interfaces

http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/extension-dev-guide/service-contracts/service-contracts.html

[How to implement service contract for a custom module in Magento 2?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/115269/how-to-implement-service-contract-for-a-custom-module-in-magento-2)