# How write a Magento 2 standard Model class

Tags: magento2, model, programming

I have create database table and want to create model,resource,Collection  class and know that how  to create.

Have follow the blog https://www.softprodigy.com/store/article/create-model-and-collection-for-custom-table-in-magento2/

Now, my question  if want use created model for API then

> - **What classes and interface need to add my Model, Resource,Collection    Class?**
> - **What API classes are need to write?**
> - **Should i create Factory class of those class?**

***In single word, how to write an standard Model class  to Magento 2***

Can any one give a brief and describe answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It got a reference answer from @kristof-at-fooman.

**And he ask me to follow @Vinai Kopp blog.**

[How to implement service contract for a custom module in Magento 2?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/115269/how-to-implement-service-contract-for-a-custom-module-in-magento-2/160617#160617)

On question Vinai have given a solid answer https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/160617/4564

So,we have to implement server contact  for our module. If API, does not need then you don't need to create API point means webapi points.

Answer (score 2):

There is very useful tool from Alan Storm named Pestle allowing you to generate all Magento 2 CRUD classes but also repository interface as well as implementation for your entity using:

```
pestle.phar generate_crud_model Pulsestorm_ToDoCrud TodoItem
```

Where Pulsestorm_ToDoCrud is name of your module, and TodoItem your new entity. I suggest you give this a try with version control in place allowing you to inspect each and every class.

Here is link to Pestle tool:

https://github.com/astorm/pestle

and here is link to article from Alan Storm explaining CRUD classes in M2 as well as usage of Pestle tool.

https://alanstorm.com/magento_2_crud_models_for_database_access/

Comment: Thanks @Marko for this answer.But how i can use  my model for API Also