# Magento 2, Cannot `getCollection()` from model factory

Tags: magento2.2, crud

Using `magento 2.2`, `CRUD`, `API`. I got an error while try to access method **getCollection()**.

> {
>       "messages": {
>           "error": [
>               {
>                   "code": 500,
>                   "message": "Fatal Error: 'Cannot declare class Iota\EShopping\Model\ResourceMode\Social\Collection, because the name is already in use' in '/home/esh_www/app/code/Iota/EShopping/Model/ResourceModel/Social/Collection.php' on line 20",
>                   "trace": "Trace is not available."
>               }
>           ]
>       }
>   }

**CALL**

```
use Magento\Customer\Model\CustomerFactory;
use Iota\EShopping\Model\SocialFactory;
use Iota\EShopping\Setup\SchSocialLogin;
use Iota\EShopping\Api\Data\SocialLoginModel as Login;

/**
 *
 * @author channarith.bong
 *        
 */
class CustomerManagement implements \Iota\EShopping\Api\CustomerManagementInterface
{

    /**
     * 
     * @param SocialFactory $socialFactory
     * @param CustomerFactory $customerFactory
     */
    public function __construct(
        SocialFactory $socialFactory,
        CustomerFactory $customerFactory
    ){
        $this->customerFactory = $customerFactory;
        $this->socialFactory = $socialFactory;
    }


    /**
     * 
     * @return string
     */
    public function validateCustomerLogin()
    {
        $socialCollection = $this->socialFactory->create()->getCollection();
    }
}
```

**Model**

```
<?php
namespace Iota\EShopping\Model;
use Magento\Framework\Data\Collection\AbstractDb;
use Magento\Framework\Model\AbstractModel;
use Magento\Framework\Model\Context;
use Magento\Framework\Model\ResourceModel\AbstractResource;
use Magento\Framework\Registry;


/**
 * 
 * @author channarith.bong
 *
 */
class Social extends AbstractModel
{
    /**
     * 
     * @param Context $context
     * @param Registry $registry
     * @param AbstractResource $resource
     * @param AbstractDb $resourceCollection
     * @param array $data
     */
    public function __construct(
        Context $context,
        Registry $registry,
        AbstractResource $resource = null,
        AbstractDb $resourceCollection = null,
        array $data = []
    ){
        parent::__construct($context, $registry, $resource, $resourceCollection, $data);
    }

    /**
     * Define resource model
     */
    protected function _construct()
    {
        $this->_init('Iota\EShopping\Model\ResourceModel\Social');
    }
}
```

**Collection**

```
<?php
namespace Iota\EShopping\Model\ResourceMode\Social;

use Magento\Framework\Model\ResourceModel\Db\Collection\AbstractCollection;

/**
 * 
 * @author channarith.bong
 *
 */
class Collection extends AbstractCollection
{
    /**
     * Define model & resource model
     */
    protected function _construct()
    {
        $this->_init('Iota\EShopping\Model\Social', 'Iota\EShopping\Model\ResourceModel\Social');
    }
}
```

**Resource**

```
<?php
namespace Iota\EShopping\Model\ResourceModel;

use Magento\Framework\Model\ResourceModel\Db\AbstractDb;
/**
 * 
 * @author channarith.bong
 *
 */
class Social extends AbstractDb
{
    /**
     * Define main table
     */
    protected function _construct()
    {
        $this->_init('iot_td_social_login', 'id');
    }
}
```

Comment: Check namespace of collection file

Comment: Check module files and folder name also try after the commands `php bin/magento cache:flush` and `php bin/magento setup:di:compile`

Comment: In `Mode Developer`, I used `php bin/magento cache:flush` and `php bin/magento setup:di:compile`

Comment: Have you corrected `namespace Iota\EShopping\Model\ResourceMode\Social;` To `namespace Iota\EShopping\Model\ResourceModel\Social;` in your `Collection.php` and same for folder name From `ResourceMode`  To `ResourceModel` ?

Comment: I'm created Magento 2 tutorials channel please Like and Support
https://www.youtube.com/channel/UC2JghzAPB7wNBDY0u-OtAig/videos

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You did the Mistake;

See your `__constact` function

```
 public function __construct(
        SocialFactory $socialFactory,
        CustomerFactory $customerFactory
    ){
        $this->customerFactory = $customerFactory;
        $this->socialFactory = $socialFactory;
    }
```

It  means `$this->socialLoginFactory` undefine variable. You have to use  `$this->socialFactory` as it is  object of `Iota\EShopping\Model\SocialFactory`.

Seems some issue in model class

Replace model class by below code:

**MOdel Class**

```
namespace Iota\EShopping\Model;

use Magento\Framework\Model\AbstractModel;

class Social extends AbstractModel
{
    protected function  _construct()
    {
       $this->_init(\Iota\EShopping\Model\ResourceModel\Social::class);
    }

}
```

**Resource MOdel Class**

```
namespace Iota\EShopping\Model\ResourceModel;
class Social extends \Magento\Framework\Model\ResourceModel\Db\AbstractDb
{

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\Model\ResourceModel\Db\Context $context
    )
    {
        parent::__construct($context);
    }

    protected function _construct()
    {
        $this->_init('iot_td_social_login', 'id');
    }

}
```

**Collection Classs**

```
namespace Iota\EShopping\Model\ResourceModel\Social;

class Collection extends \Magento\Framework\Model\ResourceModel\Db\Collection\AbstractCollection
{

    /**
     * Define resource model
     *
     * @return void
     */
    protected function _construct()
    {
        $this->_init(\Iota\EShopping\Model\Social::class,
            \Iota\EShopping\Model\ResourceModel\Social::class);
    }
}
```

**After that, you have to do di compile**

Important:

getCollection is deprecated function On `Iota\EShopping\Model\Social`.

SO, suggesting you use Collection Class directly or 
Implement Server contact interface

Comment: I update as you suggested, but I still got that error. how i need to do?

Comment: share the code of `\Iota\EShopping\Api\CustomerManagementInterface`

Comment: You have to  implement service contract to your custom module in Magento properly. Seems you have the issue on that. https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/115269/how-to-implement-service-contract-for-a-custom-module-in-magento-2/

Comment: Not yet, How to ?

Comment: `You did the Mistake;

See your __constact function

 public function __construct(
        SocialFactory $socialFactory,
        CustomerFactory $customerFactory
    ){
        $this->customerFactory = $customerFactory;
        $this->socialFactory = $socialFactory;
    }
It means $this->socialLoginFactory undefine variable. You have to use  $this->socialFactory as it is object of Iota\EShopping\Model\SocialFactory`

Comment: Yes. i saw what you told me.

Comment: I correct it but still error.