# What are the use of ExtensionAttribute JoinProcessorInterface and CollectionProcessorInterface at magento 2.2.3

Tags: magento2, api, rest-api, service-contract

I built Magento 2  Module which has a model and Service contracts/API.

During this implementation, I have followed [vinai Kopp](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/160617/4564)  article and also magento2  module `Magento_Quote`.

On this `Magento\Quote\Model\QuoteRepository`, i have found two classes

> [Magento\Framework\Api\ExtensionAttribute\JoinProcessorInterface;](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.2/app/code/Magento/Quote/Model/QuoteRepository.php#L19)
>
> [Magento\Framework\Api\SearchCriteria\CollectionProcessorInterface;](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.2/app/code/Magento/Quote/Model/QuoteRepository.php#L8)

And found  that during the implementation of **[getList()](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.2/app/code/Magento/Quote/Model/QuoteRepository.php#L225)**, these two classes used

```
  $this->collectionProcessor->process($searchCriteria, $this->quoteCollection);
  $this->extensionAttributesJoinProcessor->process($this->quoteCollection)
```

**MY repository class**

```
<?php
namespace Devamitbera\ProductSuggestion\Model;

use Devamitbera\ProductSuggestion\Api\Data\ProductSuggestionInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Api\SearchCriteriaInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Api\SearchCriteria\CollectionProcessorInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Api\ExtensionAttribute\JoinProcessorInterface;
use Devamitbera\ProductSuggestion\Api\ProductSuggestionRepositoryInterface;
use Devamitbera\ProductSuggestion\Model\ProductSuggestionFactory;
use Devamitbera\ProductSuggestion\Model\ResourceModel\ProductSuggestion as ProductSuggestionResource;
use Devamitbera\ProductSuggestion\Model\ResourceModel\ProductSuggestion\CollectionFactory as ProductSuggestionCollectionFactory ;
use Magento\Framework\Exception\NotFoundException;
use Magento\Framework\Exception\CouldNotSaveException;
use Devamitbera\ProductSuggestion\Api\Data\ProductSuggestionSearchResultInterfaceFactory;


/**
 * Repository class 
 */

class ProductSuggestionRepository  implements ProductSuggestionRepositoryInterface 
{

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\Api\ExtensionAttribute\JoinProcessorInterface
     */
    protected $extensionAttributesJoinProcessor;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\Api\SearchCriteria\CollectionProcessorInterface
     */
    protected $collectionProcessor;

    /**
     * @var \Devamitbera\ProductSuggestion\Api\Data\ProductSuggestionSearchResultInterfaceFactory
     */
    protected $productSuggestionSearchResultFactory;

    /**
     * @var \Devamitbera\ProductSuggestion\Model\ProductSuggestionFactory
     */
    protected $productSuggestionFactory;

    /**
     * @var \Devamitbera\ProductSuggestion\Model\ResourceModel\ProductSuggestion
     */
    protected $productSuggestionResource;

    /**
     * @var Devamitbera\ProductSuggestion\Model\ResourceModel\ProductSuggestion\CollectionFactory
     */
    protected $collectionFactory;

    public function __construct(
        ProductSuggestionFactory $productSuggestionFactory,
        ProductSuggestionResource $productSuggestionResource,
        ProductSuggestionCollectionFactory $CollectionFactory,
        ProductSuggestionSearchResultInterfaceFactory $productSuggestionSearchResultFactory,
        CollectionProcessorInterface  $collectionProcessor,
        JoinProcessorInterface  $extensionAttributesJoinProcessor    
    ) 
    {

        $this->collectionFactory = $CollectionFactory;
        $this->productSuggestionResource = $productSuggestionResource;
        $this->productSuggestionFactory = $productSuggestionFactory;

        $this->productSuggestionSearchResultFactory = $productSuggestionSearchResultFactory;
        $this->collectionProcessor = $collectionProcessor ?: \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance()
            ->get(\Magento\Framework\Api\SearchCriteria\CollectionProcessor::class);;
        $this->extensionAttributesJoinProcessor = $extensionAttributesJoinProcessor;
    }
     /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function delete(ProductSuggestionInterface $productSuggestion){
        $this->productSuggestionResource->delete($productSuggestion);
    }
    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function getById($id){

        $productSuggestion = $this->productSuggestionFactory->create();
        $this->productSuggestionResource->load($productSuggestion, $id);
        if(!$productSuggestion->getId()){
            throw new NotFoundException(__('unable to find the record'));
        }
        return $productSuggestion;
    }
    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function getList(SearchCriteriaInterface $searchCriteria){

        $collection = $this->collectionFactory->create();

        $searchData = $this->productSuggestionSearchResultFactory->create();
        $searchData->setSearchCriteria($searchCriteria);

        $this->collectionProcessor->process($searchCriteria, $collection);
        // $this->extensionAttributesJoinProcessor->process($collection ,null)
        $this->extensionAttributesJoinProcessor->process($collection);

        $searchData->setItems($this->quoteCollection->getItems());
        $searchData->setTotalCount($this->quoteCollection->getSize());
        return $searchData;        
    }
    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function save(ProductSuggestionInterface $productSuggestion){
        try{
          $this->productSuggestionResource->save($productSuggestion);  
        } catch (Exception $exception) {
            throw  new CouldNotSaveException(__($exception->getMessage()));
        }

        return $productSuggestion;
    }

}
```

Now, I want to know,

- why do these two classes used?
- Do I need these classes when I will implement Service contracts/API ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I know 
Yes, for Service contracts/API you have to use this both classes.

> why do this two classes use?

It will useful in api for retrieve data, `CollectionProcessorInterface` class is used for retrieving data with where condition `$searchCriteria` and `JoinProcessorInterface` is used for retrieving `custom_attribute_fields` on api call time.

> Do I need this classes when I will implement Service contracts/API ?

`Magento\Framework\Api\SearchCriteria\CollectionProcessorInterface`
This class is used for get listing with seach criteria in your api(like where condition).

`Magento\Framework\Api\ExtensionAttribute\JoinProcessorInterface`
This class is retrieve `custom_checkout_field` on api select, which is defined in `extension_attributes.xml`