# Implementing service contract Magento 2? Getting error "Class Assign\RestService\Model\ResourceModel\Hamburger\CollectionFactory does not exist"

Tags: magento2, resource-model, service-contract

I am implementing simple service contracts. don't have much knowledge about service contracts following example from here

[How to implement service contract for a custom module in Magento 2?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/115269/how-to-implement-service-contract-for-a-custom-module-in-magento-2/121705?newreg=e428ef8e681e46e6adcd2f548ac2a31f)

i am getting error of

> "Class
>   Assign\RestService\Model\ResourceModel\Hamburger\CollectionFactory
>   does not exist"

Answer (score 0):

Use this GitHub module code maybe it will help you to solve your issue

**Example1:** https://github.com/astorm/service-contract-example

Your error `"Class Assign\RestService\Model\ResourceModel\Hamburger\CollectionFactory does not exist"` says you missed to define or include `Assign\RestService\Model\ResourceModel\Hamburger\CollectionFactory` class

Just remove your whole code related to the service contract and use above module of Alan Storm

OR

**Example2:** https://github.com/magentow/ServiceContract

**Example3:** https://github.com/navarr/m2-module-regionlookup