# Magento Recommended way to add comment to order

Tags: magento2, sales-order, magento2.3, best-practice, order-comment

I am looking for the Magento recommended best practice for adding a comment to an order. I can easily accomplish this using things such as `$order->addCommentToStatusHistory($message)->save()` and similar actions. However I know that using a direct `save` action is not recommended on models and you should instead us managers/repositories.

I have also found that there is a `\Magento\Sales\Api\OrderStatusHistoryRepositoryInterface` now which provides the `save` function. So what I'm trying to figure out is how to approach this properly. This is my best guess.

```
private $orderStatusHistoryRepository;

public function __construct(
    \Magento\Sales\Api\OrderStatusHistoryRepositoryInterface $orderStatusHistoryRepository
) {
    $this->orderStatusHistoryRepository = $orderStatusHistoryRepository;
}

public function myFunction(\Magento\Sales\Api\Data\OrderInterface $order)
{
    //... additional logic here
    $history = $order->addCommentToStatusHistory($message);
    $this->orderStatusHistoryRepository->save($history);
}
```

What I'm not certain about is if this is the proper approach AND should I also be saving the order using `OrderRepositoryInterface`, or if that is unnecessary.

I have looked through a lot of questions and answers around this as well as looking through some tutorials and documentation. However all of these provide conflicting information and most of them recommend ways that I know are not Magento best practice.

If there is documentation out there that would answer my question and I have overlooked it please point me in the right direction.

This is for Magento 2.3.0.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As per as,  current Magento code, there is two way we can save comment

Using Order repository :  `Magento\Sales\Api\OrderStatusHistoryRepositoryInterface:save()`

Using Order history: `Magento\Sales\Api\OrderRepositoryInterface:save()` and 
 `\Magento\Sales\Api\Data\OrderInterface::addCommentToStatusHistory`

What is between two:

`OrderStatusHistoryRepositoryInterface:save`  directly related with `sales_order_status_history` .It is behavior same like basic Crud service contact provider with the model and table. Like [How to implement service contract for a custom module in Magento 2?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/115269/how-to-implement-service-contract-for-a-custom-module-in-magento-2/160617#160617)

```
$history =$this->historyFactory->create();
$history->setParentId($orderid)
     ->setStatus($status)
      ->setComment($comment)
        ->setIsVisibleOnFront($isVisibleOnFront)
        ->setIsCustomerNotified($customerNotifiedflag)
        ->setCreatedAt($createdAt);
$this->OrderStatusHistoryRepository->save($history);
```

And where to save using `Magento\Sales\Api\OrderRepositoryInterface:save()` is behavior same like first but as for save for order comment you have to  call other function addCommentToStatusHistory() of  `Magento\Sales\Model\Order`

```
$orderId  = 1;
/**
 * orderRepository instance of  Magento\Sales\Api\OrderRepositoryInterface
 */
$order = $this->orderRepository->get($orderId);
/**
 * $order is instead of  Magento\Sales\Model\Order or \Magento\Sales\Api\Data\OrderInterface
 */
$order->addCommentToStatusHistory('my command', $status = false, $isVisibleOnFront = true);
$this->orderRepository->save($order);
```

**Second  different and most important:**

For `OrderStatusHistoryRepositoryInterface:save()` ,you have  to send order status code to `SetStatus()` and it ***does not change Magento order status*** as it directly **related with Order Service contact or order resource mode**l. and its only perform single table operations.

Where   order repository save() **can  changes order status  if you send order status  to**  `addCommentToStatusHistory($comment,$OrderStatusCode,$isVisibleOnFront)`

*As per as,my idea, If you want to only  add order command and you have already  requirement  like $orderid,$status,$isVisibleOnFront etc*

Comment: Thanks for explaining both approaches. Those both make sense. It looks like I was attempting a hybrid of the two which is why it wasn't working. I just got it working using `OrderRepositoryInterface`. Where I got confused was since `addCommentToStatusHistory` returns the history object I thought I had to save it instead of the order.