# which model extend AbstractExtensibleModel by default

Tags: magento2, model, extension-attributes

which model extend AbstractExtensibleModel by default so i can use extension attributes with it ?

Answer (score 0):

If you will use Model class means `{Vendor}_{ModuleName}_Model_{EntityClass}` as Data Model class of your API Data Interface then you can Use `AbstractExtensibleModel` As Extends class of `{Vendor}_{ModuleName}_Model_{EntityClass}`.

See  vinai Koop  article [How to implement service contract for a custom module in Magento 2?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/115269/how-to-implement-service-contract-for-a-custom-module-in-magento-2/160617#160617) 
For more details

**Example:**

```
namespace VinaiKopp\Kitchen\Model;

use Magento\Framework\Model\AbstractExtensibleModel;
use VinaiKopp\Kitchen\Api\Data\HamburgerExtensionInterface;
use VinaiKopp\Kitchen\Api\Data\HamburgerInterface;

class Hamburger extends AbstractExtensibleModel implements HamburgerInterface
{
```

Comment: yes i know, i mean which entity extensible by default for example quote, ........

Comment: yes. right `\Magento\Store\Model\Group` an exmaple