# REST V1/customers adding a new extension attribute Magento 2.3.1

Tags: customer, rest-api, magento2.3.1

I have added a new field as **"is_seller"** in registration page **(same as "is_subscribed).** If the checkbox is clicked the customer Id will be saved to another table with some additional values.

It was done through the event. But using v1/customers how can I achieve this. 
When I tried to add it thorugh the parameters  as below

```
"customer": {
        "email": "test@test2.com",
        "firstname": "test,
        "lastname": "test",
        "store_id": 1,
        "website_id": 1,
        "is_seller":1
    },
     "password": "Password1"
```

I am getting the following error

> Message: Property "IsSeller" does not have accessor method
>   "getIsSeller" in class "Magento\Customer\Api\Data\CustomerInterface".

I tried using extension attributes also, but it is not working.

Comment: any soluction on this

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a module to override "Magento\Customer\Api\Data\CustomerInterface" interface and add your methods in it "getIsSeller" and "setIsSeller". Once this is done, override the model "Magento\Customer\Model\Data\Customer" and add the definition of these methods in it. once this is done, you can set and get this value to save and fetch from DB.

Don't forget the add the preferences for these files in di.xml file to use your module's files instead of original.

Comment: I have create a module and created extension_attribute.xml  as <extension_attributes for="Magento\Customer\Api\Data\CustomerInterface">
   <attribute code="is_seller" type="Test\Selling\Data\SellerManagementInterface"/>
</extension_attributes> and created interface with getIsSeller and setIsSeller functions. After that created a plugin following this article  https://store.fooman.co.nz/blog/an-introduction-to-extension-attributes.html. Now I am getting the following error "Fatal Error: 'Uncaught Error: Cannot instantiate interface Test\\Selling\\Api\\Data\\SellerManagementInterface

Comment: Check the value of "type". API word is missing in the type path. Correct it and try once.

Answer (score 0):

You have to implement [extension_attribute](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/extension-dev-guide/attributes.html) for `is_seller` attribute then you have to enable to add is_seller to the database.

First,  read the article https://store.fooman.co.nz/blog/an-introduction-to-extension-attributes.html

First, you have to implement the [**service contract**](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/115269/how-to-implement-service-contract-for-a-custom-module-in-magento-2) for your custom table to save the data.

Assume that

**your data interface class is**

`StackExchange\ServiceContactTest\Api\Data\CustomInterface`

**And RepositoryInterface  is** `StackExchange\ServiceContactTest\Api\CustomRepositoryInterface`

First, you have to add `is_seller` as extension_attribute for data interface `Magento\Customer\Api\Data\CustomerInterface`.

Create `extension_attributes.xml` at `app/code/{Vendor}/{ModuleName}/etc`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Api/etc/extension_attributes.xsd">
    <extension_attributes for="Magento\Customer\Api\Data\CustomerInterface">
        <attribute code="is_seller"  type="StackExchange\ServiceContactTest\Api\Data\CustomInterface" />
    </extension_attributes>
</config>
```

After that Using plugin on  `Magento\Customer\Api\CustomerRepositoryInterface`, you need to save this custom table data.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Customer\Api\CustomerRepositoryInterface">
        <plugin name="save_seller_table" type="StackExchange\ServiceContactTest\Plugin\OrderSave"/>
    </type>
</config>
```

## Plugin Class

```
<?php

namespace StackExchange\ServiceContactTest\Plugin;

use Magento\Framework\Exception\CouldNotSaveException;

class OrderSave
{

...

    public function afterSave(
        \Magento\Customer\Api\CustomerRepositoryInterface $subject,
        \Magento\Customer\Api\Data\CustomerInterface $resultOrder
    ) {
        $resultOrder = $this->saveFoomanAttribute($resultOrder);

        return $resultOrder;
    }

    private function saveFoomanAttribute(\Magento\Customer\Api\Data\CustomerInterface $customer)
    {
        $extensionAttributes = $customer->getExtensionAttributes();
        if (
            null !== $extensionAttributes &&
            null !== $extensionAttributes->getIsSeller()
        ) {
            $foomanAttributeValue = $extensionAttributes->getIsSeller()->getValue();
            try {
                // The actual implementation of the repository is omitted
                // but it is where you would save to the database (or any other persistent storage)
                $this->foomanExampleRepository->save($customer->getEntityId(), $foomanAttributeValue);
            } catch (\Exception $e) {
                throw new CouldNotSaveException(
                    __('Could not add attribute to order: "%1"', $e->getMessage()),
                    $e
                );
            }
        }
        return $customer;
    }
```

Comment: When I tried to print $extensionAttributes = $customer->getExtensionAttributes(); in the plugin I am getting null value. Following method is used for creating customer {
 "customer": {
  "email": "test@test18.com",
  "firstname": "test",
  "lastname": test",
  "store_id": 1,
  "website_id": 1,
  "extension_attributes": {
        "is_seller": true
        }
 },
  "password": "Password1"
  
}