# Load resource models without using deprecated getResource

Tags: magento2, coding-standards

I'm using `Magento\Newsletter\Model\ResourceModel\Subscriber::loadByCustomerData`

Code is like this

```
 /** @var \Magento\Customer\Api\Data\CustomerInterface $customer */

 [...]

 $subscriber = $this->subscriberFactory->create();

 $array = $subscriber->getResource()
     ->loadByCustomerData($customer);
 [...]
```

I spotted that getResource is `@deprecated because resource models should be used directly` which makes sense.

What would be the correct way to do this without using deprecated code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The correct way is that calling the Resouce model `Magento\Newsletter\Model\ResourceModel\Subscriber` directly at your **model class or service contact class** instead of call **Model class** `getResource()`.

As Magento following Service concept design pattern https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/extension-dev-guide/service-contracts/service-contracts.html, So model class used as Data provide a class that `getResource()` is deprecated at magento2.

Like `\Magento\Cms\Api\Data\BlockInterface` is rewrite  by `\Magento\Cms\Model\Block`.

```
/**
* @var $subscriber \Magento\Newsletter\Model\ResourceModel\Subscriber
*/
$subscriberResource = $this->subscriberResource;

$array = $subscriberResource->loadByCustomerData($customer);
```

Check the [How to implement service contract for a custom module in Magento 2?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/115269/how-to-implement-service-contract-for-a-custom-module-in-magento-2/160617) about service contract.

**Example:**

```
<?php
namespace {NameSpace};

// Alias of Class
use Magento\Newsletter\Model\ResourceModel\Subscriber as SubscriberResourceModel;

class {Classname}{
    
    private $subscriberResource;
    public function __construct(
        SubscriberResourceModel $subscriberResource,
        .....
    ) {
        .....
        $this->subscriberResource = $subscriberResource;
        ....
    }   
}
```

Comment: Can you show how to declare in constructor?