# Annotating methods in API interfaces to work with DataObjectHelper::populateWithArray

Tags: magento2, api

I'm trying to build a proper CRUD module for Magento 2.
My module contains for now an entity called `Author`.
This module contains the main entity table and a many to many relations table with the store views (similar to the cms pages and static blocks).
I've created, among others, an interface for the main model called `[Namespace]\[Module]\Api\Data\AuthorInterface` following the same guidelines as for CMS pages.

```
interface AuthorInterface extends ExtensibleDataInterface
{
     const AUTHOR_ID    = 'author_id';
     const NAME         = 'name';
     const STORE_ID     = 'store_id'; //this is missing in the cms page interface
     /**
     * Get ID
     *
     * @return int|null
     */
    public function getId();

    /**
     * Get name
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getName();
    /**
     * set id
     *
     * @param $id
     * @return AuthorInterface
     */
    public function setId($id);

    /**
     * set name
     *
     * @param $name
     * @return AuthorInterface
     */
    public function setName($name);
    /**
     * @param $storeId
     * @return AuthorInterface
     */
    public function setStoreId($storeId);

    /**
     * @return array
     */
    public function getStoreId();
}
```

Now here come the differences and problems.
The cms page interface does not contain the constant `STORE_ID` nor the methods `setStoreId` or `getStoreId`.
But from my point of view they should be there.
Also the cms pages save action uses the `$page->save()` call that [is deprecated](https://magento.stackexchange.com/q/114929/146).
I decided to use repositories.
So my save action looks something like this:

```
$data = $this->getRequest()->getPostValue();
....
$author->setName($data['name']);//don't worry, I have a verification for the existence of $data['name']
$author->setStoreId($data['store_id']); 
$this->authorRepository->save($author); //authorRepository is an instance of \[Namespace]\[Module]\Api\AuthorRepositoryInterface
```

This works nicely, but what if my entity has a lot of fields, not just a name?
I don't want to call `->set...` a hundred times. Plus, if I add one more field, I need to modify my code.
I discovered the method `\Magento\Framework\Api\DataObjectHelper::populateWithArray`.
Now I can simply call

```
$this->dataObjectHelper->populateWithArray($author, $data , '\[Namespace]\[Module]\Api\Data\AuthorInterface'); //where dataObjectHelper is an instance of \Magento\Framework\Api\DataObjectHelper
```

This, again, works flawlessly except for the `store_id`.
I get an exception `Class array does not exist` because the annotation for `getStoreId` says `@return array`.   can confirm that changing this annotation changes the exception message or works when changing the return type to `string`. But my store id is going to be an array not a string.

**What is the proper way to handle this kind of case?**

**[EDIT]**
I could go around this by using

```
$data = $this->getRequest()->getPostValue();
...
if (isset($data['store_id'])) {
    $author->setStoreId($data['store_id']);
    unset($data['store_id']);
}
$this->dataObjectHelper->populateWithArray($author, $data , '\[Namespace]\[Module]\Api\Data\AuthorInterface');
```

But this looks dirty.

Comment: Are getStoreId return array? 8|

Comment: Yes, getStoreId will return an array. The ids of the stores associated to my entity.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Magento service layers support only **homogeneous** arrays.

So you cannot define type as just array. You should define it as TypeName[], for example int[].