# Magento 2 - Why is Magento\Checkout\Model\Cart deprecated?

Tags: magento2, cart, service-contract, magento-2.1, deprecated

Since Magento 2.1, Cart has a `@deprecated` tag. Nevertheless, it is still used by Magento itself to store products when shopping. Is the deprecation intended, and if so, and what should we use instead?

Comment: Welcome to Magento.SE! Great question! You may think to revise the title a bit so it doesn't ask for subjective answer. For instance, "Should I still use?" is probably better than "why was it deprecated"

Comment: Thanks for your reply, philwinkle! However, @deprecated already implies that it should not be use anymore. I just wanted to know what it is replaced by, and because it is still actively used by Magento, I have a small suspicion that the class was deprecated by mistake. :)

Comment: Outside of a core team member the answer cannot be *canonically* answered. But I think that as it stands it is a perfectly valid question.

Comment: for the record. deprecation removed in https://github.com/magento/magento2/pull/11070

Answer (score 24):

My guess is that **the Magento team is planning to implement service contracts for this class.**

However as of 2.1 if you check the `app/code/Magento/Checkout/Api` folder there's no class (yet) that implements such service contract.

I assume it'll happen at some point and the Magento team flagged that model to be deprecated in the future. However as I said and as you said, it is still used in the software so you can still keep using it for now.

I reckon this `@deprecated` tag is a similar flag as [the one for the `load()` method from `Magento\Framework\Model\AbstractMode`](https://magento.stackexchange.com/q/114929/2380)

Same goes for the XML `<action>` tag which is deprecated but still is the only option in some cases: http://goo.gl/laVP35 and is still widely used in 2.1: https://github.com/magento/magento2/search?l=xml&q=action&utf8=%E2%9C%93

Answer (score 18):

The commit that deprecated the cart model is [c4e9a77403655646a18d4277de96429c86bd34fa](https://github.com/magento/magento2/commit/c4e9a77403655646a18d4277de96429c86bd34fa#diff-aad85c7d6b9a0cf0c2284b3db8efe796) with the message

> MAGETWO-51558: Mark Checkout Cart model as deprecated

This doesn't tell much, especially since this is the only commit that references the internal ticket number "MAGETWO-51558"

Since `\Magento\Checkout\Api` still does not contain any new service contracts and `\Magento\Quote\Api\CartItemRepositoryInterface` cannot replace the cart model either, I agree with your suspicion that it has been deprecated too early.

Of course, a final answer can only be given by a Magento employee.