# What should we use instead of the Magento\Checkout\Model\Cart model?

Tags: cart, magento2.2, best-practice, class, di

The `Magento\Checkout\Model\Cart` class was marked as **deprecated** a long time ago (since 2.1 ver.). What should I use instead of it to work with a customers cart?

I know that I can work directly with a `Quote` model, but maybe exists some interface which replaced the `Cart` model functional?

**PS:** I read the [answer given here](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/122722/magento-2-why-is-magento-checkout-model-cart-deprecated) about "*Why it is deprecated?*", but I need the information about "*What should I use instead?*".

Comment: https://magento.stackexchange.com/tags/magento-1.9.3.3/info

okay i have changed this

Answer (score 3):

As far as I know, there is no replacement as of now (Magento 2.2), the class was simply deprecated as an indication that the logic it handles will be refactored in the future. Just continue to use it for now until a proper replacement is implemented.

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
\Magento\Quote\Api\CartRepositoryInterface
```

For more information, you can see this post : [Resolve cart deprecated](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/248374/magento-2-programatically-adding-product-to-cart-adds-item-with-price-of-zero)