# Add multiple items to cart in Magento2

Tags: magento2, addtocart, controllers, ajax

I am implementing add to cart functionality from ajax using product id.

This is my code of template file

```
  <tr class="border_bottom child-items  selected">
                        <td >11</td>                            
                        <td>Test 2</td>
                    </tr>
  <tr class="border_bottom child-items  selected">
                        <td >12</td>                            
                        <td>Test 2</td>
                    </tr>

 <script>
 var selectedItems = [];
    jQuery("#table tr.selected").each(function(){
        selectedItems.push(jQuery('td:first', this).html());
    });
    var additemUrl = "<?php echo $this->getUrl().'product/addproduct/additems' ?>";
        jQuery.ajax({
             url: additemUrl,
             type: "POST",
             data : 'selectedItems='+selectedItems,
             dataType: 'json',
             success : function(result) {
                console.log('success');                               
             }
        }); 
   </script>
```

Here is my controller file.

```
 use Magento\Framework\Controller\ResultFactory;
 use Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action;
 use Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context;

class AddItems extends Action {
protected $formKey;   
protected $cart;
protected $product;

public function __construct(
    \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context,
    \Magento\Framework\Data\Form\FormKey $formKey,
    \Magento\Checkout\Model\Cart $cart,
    \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product $product,
    array $data = []) {
        $this->formKey = $formKey;
        $this->cart = $cart;
        $this->product = $product;      
        parent::__construct($context);
    }

public function execute()
 { 
   $selectedItems = $this->getRequest()->getPost('selectedItems');      
    echo '<pre>';
    print_r($selectedItems);exit;
  try{
      $params = array(
                    'form_key' => $this->formKey->getFormKey(),
                    'product' => $selectedItems, //product Id
                    'qty'   =>1 //quantity of product                
                );              
        //Load the product based on productID   
        $_product = $this->product->load($selectedItems);       
        $this->cart->addProduct($_product, $params);
        $this->cart->save();
        $status = 1;    
  }
  catch (\Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException $e) {
         $this->messageManager->addException(
             $e,
             __('%1', $e->getMessage())
         );
          $status = 0;
     } catch (\Exception $e) {
         $this->messageManager->addException($e, __('error.'));
          $status = 0;
     }  
    $result = array();
    $result['status'] = $status;
    $resultJson = $this->resultFactory->create(ResultFactory::TYPE_JSON);
    $resultJson->setData($result);
    return $resultJson;
   }
 }
```

Here i need to read each element from the selectedItems array and add to cart. How this can be implemented.

If only item passed from the ajax , I need to add only one item to the cart.

Can anyone help me on this issue please.

Comment: can you add namespace in above controller to see where you are at them moment? what is the issue you are facing ?

Comment: Is it working for you?

Comment: @RohanHapani, i am trying it now

Comment: I have updated controller as per your logic. Please check my answer for more information

Comment: Did you check with my updated controller code ?

Comment: @SaneerLadani, no i am using other answer, let me check yours too, there i am facing issue

Comment: @RohanHapani, i am getting below error, attribute name is invalid. Reset the name and try again

Comment: @RohanHapani, can you look into it please? I am getting empty array in $cart_product->getData()

Comment: Just add ->addAttributeToSelect('*') before ->addAttributeToFilter

Comment: @RohanHapani, yes added and flushed cache still empty array

Comment: @RohanHapani, $this->getRequest()->getPost('selectedItems');  is not coming as array, I am telling you this since from yesterday

Comment: Man !! :D I already told you 3 times that we do not need to get in array. product id used in comma separate not in array format.

And which you asked that already full fill. still, you removed as accepted answer :D Good.

Comment: @RohanHapani, yes its not coming as array, but coming as comma separated only,  11 , 12 like this, That is my mistake i accepted without testing it

Comment: @Jafar Please read carefully what I right here. https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/243628/51810 Read syntax carefully.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/88666/discussion-between-jafar-pinjar-and-rohan-hapani).

Comment: Easy to use this extension [Magento 2 Add Multiple Products to Cart](https://www.magespark.com/magento-2-add-multiple-products-to-cart-extension.html)

Comment: Since 2.1 cart has been deprecated, you can follow with threat to resolve :
[resolve cart deprecated](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/248374/magento-2-programatically-adding-product-to-cart-adds-item-with-price-of-zero)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replace your controller with below code

```
 use Magento\Framework\Controller\ResultFactory;
 use Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action;
 use Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context;

/**
 * Responsible for loading page content.
 *
 * This is a basic controller that only loads the corresponding layout file. It may duplicate other such
 * controllers, and thus it is considered tech debt. This code duplication will be resolved in future releases.
 */
class AddItems extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action
{

    protected $formKey;   
    protected $cart;
    protected $product;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context,
        \Magento\Framework\Data\Form\FormKey $formKey,
        \Magento\Checkout\Model\Cart $cart,
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductFactory $product,
        array $data = []
    ) {
        $this->formKey = $formKey;
        $this->cart = $cart;
        $this->product = $product;      
        parent::__construct($context);
    }

    public function execute()
    { 
       $selectedItems = $this->getRequest()->getPost('selectedItems');      
        $selectedItems = explode(",",$selectedItems);
        try{
        foreach ($selectedItems as $key => $selectedItem) {

            $params = array(
                'form_key' => $this->formKey->getFormKey(),
                'product_id' => $selectedItem, //product Id
                'qty'   =>1 //quantity of product                
            );
            $_product = $this->product->create()->load($selectedItem);       
            $this->cart->addProduct($_product, $params);
        }
            $this->cart->save();
            $status = 1;
        } catch (\Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException $e) {
            $this->messageManager->addException($e,__('%1', $e->getMessage()));
            $status = 0;
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            $this->messageManager->addException($e, __('error.'));
            $status = 0;
        }
        $result = array();
        $result['status'] = $status;
        $resultJson = $this->resultFactory->create(ResultFactory::TYPE_JSON);
        $resultJson->setData($result);
        return $resultJson;
    }
}
```

**Remove generated folder.**

Please check it and let me know in the case of any issue

Comment: for me quote id not retrieved when inserted first time.

Comment: hello @Saneer, I am facing problem, when setting custom price for each product

Comment: hi @Saneer, i need to store quoteid in my custom table with product id, but i am getting quoteid as empty here,https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/274172/quote-id-is-empty-when-inserting-multiple-records-into-cart-in-magento2

Answer (score 2):

Add this below code in your controller :

```
protected $formKey;
protected $_productFactory;
protected $_cart;
protected $messageManager;
public function __construct(
    Context $context,
    \Magento\Framework\Data\Form\FormKey $formKey,
    \Magento\Framework\Message\ManagerInterface $managerInterface,
    \Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductFactory $productFactory,
    \Magento\Checkout\Model\Cart $cart
) {
    parent::__construct($context);
    $this->formKey = $formKey;
    $this->_productFactory = $productFactory;
    $this->_cart = $cart;
    $this->messageManager = $managerInterface;
}

public function execute()
{
    $selectedItems = $this->getRequest()->getPost('selectedItems');      
    //$cart_product = your product data collection or 
    $cart_product = $this->_productFactory->create()->getCollection()->addAttributeToFilter('entity_id',array($selectedItems));

    if ($cart_product) {
        foreach ($cart_product as $key => $value) {
            $custom_optinons_value = '';
            if (isset($value['super_attribute']) || !empty($value['super_attribute'])) {
                $custom_optinons_value = $value['super_attribute'];
            }
            $this->addCartProduct($value['id'], $value['qty'], $custom_optinons_value);
        }
        $this->_cart->save();
    }
    $this->messageManager->addSuccess('Shopping cart updated succesfully.');
}

public function addCartProduct($productID, $productQty, $config_options)
{
    $product = $this->_productFactory->create()->load($productID);
    $info = new \Magento\Framework\DataObject(
        [
            'form_key' => $this->formKey->getFormKey(),
            'product_id' => $productID,
            'qty' => $productQty,
            'super_attribute' => $config_options,
        ]
    );
    return $this->_cart->addProduct($product, $info);
}
```

Create **sections.xml** at `app/code/VendorName/Abc/etc/frontend`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Customer:etc/sections.xsd">
    <action name="abc/index/addtocart">
        <section name="cart"/>
    </action>
</config>
```

Controller path : **VendorName/Abc/Controller/Index/Addtocart.php**

remove var and generated folder.

Comment: i am not cleared with super attribute and section.xml file

Comment: sections.xml for add product to cart without page load and super_attribute is for that if custom options available in product then it will also add to cart. In my code, i set like if custom option available then custom option also add. Otherwise, as normal way as like simple product, procedure will be run.

Comment: will it call same controller from ajax?, can you update me as per my code above

Comment: Yes. Just copy my controller code into your controller and add your controller action in your sections.xml

Comment: how to call that through ajax?, also where you are reading the params sent from ajax

Comment: What you want to call?

Comment: selectedItems i am passing in ajax on button click and adding items to cart

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/88611/discussion-between-rohan-hapani-and-jafar-pinjar).

Comment: I am getting getting internal server error @Rohan

Comment: Rohan, it is not  working for me

Comment: $value['qty'] how can i get qty ?? collection have qty ? which user add in cusotm collection from ?

Comment: You can use $value->getQty()

Answer (score 0):

I just add 20 sentes.
When you use `\Magento\Checkout\Model\Cart` and method `public function addProduct($productInfo, $requestInfo = null)`

And your wishes are adding some simples products as coupled on one configurable then don't forget to use only product object for $productInfo with clone:
`$this->_cart->addProduct(clone $product, $params);`