# Magento 2.3 : Load new custom items into Shopping Cart when an button is clicked

Tags: magento2, cart, magento2.3, extensions, mini-cart

I am making my own module and now I added a button into it. If this button is clicked I want to get products with an AJAX request from a REST API (I already get my products, this is no problem).

**Afterwards I want to load this products into the cart**. This is were I have the main problem. I also want that the minicart gets updated. Is there a way to do this? I am very desperate.

This is my AJAX request (Yes I know that I currently not store the data I get back, I will add this when I have the solution for the problem I mentioned before):

```
jQuery("#getCart").on("click", function(){
            jQuery.ajax({
                url:"http://192.168.10.106:8080/api/cart/",
                type:"GET", //First change type to method here
                headers: {
                  'X-Requested-With':  'XMLHttpRequest',
                  'Accept': '*/*',
                  'Cache-Control':'no-cache',
                },
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                data:
                {
                    "_customerID": 1, //for tests
                }
                success:function(response) {
                },
                error:function(){
                  alert("An Error occurred. Try again later");
                }
            });
          }
      });
```

This AJAX is in my `view/frontend/templates/button_getcart.phtml file.`

Can someboy please help me? I really need a solution for this and I am new to Magento 2.

Comment: So, It seems like you want add to cart product programmatically. Right?

Comment: Yes right, but it could be that the price is not the same as the price, that is saved in Magento. The Data i get from the REST API is (Price, ProductID [ID saved Magento] and amount)

Comment: Is there really nobody who can help me?

Comment: This is a great problem.

Comment: My company is struggling with this too.

Comment: Do these products exist in magento? Just the price is different?

Comment: Yes exactly. Thanks for your comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please add following code in your button_getcart.phtml

```
jQuery("#getCart").on("click", function(){
            jQuery.ajax({
                url:"http://192.168.10.106:8080/api/cart/",
                type:"GET", //First change type to method here
                headers: {
                  'X-Requested-With':  'XMLHttpRequest',
                  'Accept': '*/*',
                  'Cache-Control':'no-cache',
                },
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                data:
                {
                    "_customerID": 1, //for tests
                }
                success:function(response) {
            jQuery.ajax({
                        type: "post",
                        url: <?= $block->getUrl('vendor/extension/index') ?>,
                        data: {
                        productId: response.Product_ID
                    }
                        success: function (data) {
                    console.log(data);
                        }
                    });
                },
                error:function(){
                  alert("An Error occurred. Try again later");
                }
            });
          }
      });
```

And create your controller as :

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\Extension\Controller\Index;
use Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action;
use Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context;
use Magento\Framework\Data\Form\FormKey;
use Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\JsonFactory;
use Magento\Checkout\Model\Cart;
use Magento\Catalog\Model\Product;
class Post extends Action
{
    protected $formKey;   
    protected $cart;
    protected $product;
    public function __construct(
        Context $context,
    JsonFactory $resultJsonFactory,
        FormKey $formKey,
        Cart $cart,
        Product $product) {
            $this->formKey = $formKey;
        $this->resultJsonFactory = $resultJsonFactory;
            $this->cart = $cart;
            $this->product = $product;      
            parent::__construct($context);
    }
    public function execute()
     { 
    $result = $this->resultJsonFactory->create();
        $productId = $this->getRequest()->getParam('productId');
        try {
        $params = array(
                    'form_key' => $this->formKey->getFormKey(),
                    'product' => $productId, 
                    'qty'   =>1
                );              
            $product = $this->product->load($productId);       
            $this->cart->addProduct($product, $params);
            $this->cart->save();
        $result->setData(['message' => __("Product is added in cart")]);
        return $result; 
    } catch(\Exception $e) {
        $result->setData(['error' => __($e->getMessage())]);
        return $result; 
    }
     }
}
```

Please change Vendor and Extension in both files as per your vendor and module name.

I hope this works for you. If still you face any issue, please let me know.

Comment: Thank you very much, worked fine for me

Comment: I am always happy to help.

Answer (score 0):

You can update the mini cart via JS:

```
<script>
    require([
        'Magento_Customer/js/customer-data'
    ], function (customerData) {
        var sections = ['cart'];
        customerData.invalidate(sections);
        customerData.reload(sections, true);
    });
</script>
```

or @rohan-hapani has developed a controller for adding an array of items to the cart from an AJAX request and refreshing the mini cart. Please see the controller in his answers at the following posts.

[magento 2 : Add multiple product to cart](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/243621/magento-2-add-multiple-product-to-cart/243628#243628)

[Add multiple items to cart in Magento2](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/258679/add-multiple-items-to-cart-in-magento2)

Please post your files and I'd be happy to help further. Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for your answer, will try this in a moment!