# Best Way to Load a Custom Model in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, model, best-practice, crud

Because it was hard for me to find the right way, below you could find the best practice I made mine. Enjoy, correct my English if needed and say me I'm wrong if I am. :)

**Edit :** *... and I found out I was wrong on some aspect. So I updated the original post after Raphael's answers helped me to understand more. Thanks to him !*

**Concept used below** :

It will be easier for you to understand codes and explanations below if you are comfortable with these concepts :

- Injection Dependency (as every `$this->variable` variables in codes are injected)
- Service Contract and Repository
- Factory

**Context** :

Just to have more context, imagine we have a module correctly construct with :

- a block class CustomBlock containing a method `getCustomModel($id)`,
- this method returns a CustomModel object based on the id passed in param,
- CustomModel type correspond to the model in `\Vendor\Module\Model\CustomModel`
- This model comes with its resource model (in `\Vendor\Module\Model\ResourceModel\CustomModel`)
- and with its repository (in `\Vendor\Module\Model\CustomModelRepository`).

**Question** :

- What's the best practice to let the all thing loading a CustomModel object ?

You can't use the `load()` from a CustomModel object since this method is deprecated.

The good practice says that you have to use the CustomModel Service Contract. Service contracts are data interfaces (e.g. CustomModelInterface) and service interfaces (e.g. CustomModelRepositoryInterface). So my block looks like this :

```
/** @var SlideRepositoryInterface  */
protected $slideRepository;

/**
 * CustomBlock constructor
 * ...
 * @param CustomModelRepositoryInterface $customModelRepository
 * ...
 */
public function __construct(
...
CustomModelRepositoryInterface $customModelRepository
...
) {
    $this->customModelRepository = $customModelRepository;
}

public function getCustomModel($id) {
    return $this->customModelRepository->get($id);
}
```

First of all, we inject the `CustomModelRepositoryInterface` object in the constructor and we use it in our `getCustomModel()` method.

In the class `Api\CustomModelRepositoryInterface` there is not a lot. Generally (but nothing prevent you to do differently) you will declare basic methods : `get`, `getList`, `save`, `delete`, `deleteById`. For the purpose of this topic, below is just the `get` method declaration :

```
/**
 * Get info by id
 *
 * @param int $id
 * @return Data\CustomModelInterface
 * @throws \Magento\Framework\Exception\NoSuchEntityException
 */
public function get($id);
```

Ok, but if my CustomModel Interface is called by dependency injection in my block constructor, where is the code ?
For answer to this question you have to explain to Magento where find the class implementing this interface. In the etc/di.xml file of the module, you have to add :

```
<preference for="Vendor\Module\Api\CustomModelRepositoryInterface" type="Vendor\Module\Model\CustomModelRepository" />
```

So `CustomModelRepositoryInterface` class is a service interface. In implementing it you will have to implementing also data interfaces (at least `Vendor\Module\Api\Data\CustomModelInterface` and `Vendor\Module\Api\Data\CustomModelSearchResultsInterface`). Your model will have to implement `Vendor\Module\Api\Data\CustomModelInterface` and add `<preference ... />` lines for each one of your interfaces. Finally at anytime you use service contract, think in `mySomethingInterface` not anymore in `mySomething` : let magento use the `di.xml` preferences mechanism.

Ok, what comes next ? As we inject `CustomModelRepositoryInterface` in the block constructor, we get an `CustomModelRepository` object. `CustomModelRepository` has to implement the method declare in `CustomModelRepositoryInterface`. So we have this in `Vendor\Module\Model\CustomModelRepository` :

```
public function get($id) {
    $customModel = $this->customModelFactory->create();
    $customModel->load($id);
    if (!$customModel->getId()) {
      throw new NoSuchEntityException(__('CustomModel with id "%1" does not exist.', $id));
    }
    return $customModel;
}
```

What we are doing ? We create an empty `CustomModel` object thanks to the factory. Next we load data in the `CustomModel` using the load model method. Next we return a `NoSuchEntityException` if we failed to load the `CustomModel` with the id in params. But if everything's ok, we return the model object and life continue.

But wow...! In this example what is that ?

```
$customModel->load($id);
```

Isn't the same deprecated `load` method than at the beginning ? Yes, it is. I think it's a shame, but you have to use it since in this load() method there are some events dispatched and developer could listening for them (see Raphael's answer below).

In future, we will be save by Entity Manager. It's another story as a new Magento 2 concept, but if you want to drop an eye on, Entity Manager is already implemented in the Resource Model of CMS Page (v2.1) :

```
public function load(AbstractModel $object, $value, $field = null)
{
    $pageId = $this->getPageId($object, $value, $field);
    if ($pageId) {
        $this->entityManager->load($object, $pageId);
    }
    return $this;
}
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

### Best practice: via the service contract

The best practice is always to use the service contract whenever it's possible. You can find the list of reasons here: [Magento 2: what are the benefits of using service contracts?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/q/115398/2380)

For details on how to implement a service contract I suggest you check this topic: [How to implement service contract for a custom module in Magento 2?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/q/115269/2380)

### If no service contract available

If there is no service contract available, you should use the model repository `get` method. Using this method, you benefit from the magento caching system for example for the `CategoryRepository` class:

```
public function get($categoryId, $storeId = null)
{
    $cacheKey = null !== $storeId ? $storeId : 'all';
    if (!isset($this->instances[$categoryId][$cacheKey])) {
        /** @var Category $category */
        $category = $this->categoryFactory->create();
        if (null !== $storeId) {
            $category->setStoreId($storeId);
        }
        $category->load($categoryId);
        if (!$category->getId()) {
            throw NoSuchEntityException::singleField('id', $categoryId);
        }
        $this->instances[$categoryId][$cacheKey] = $category;
    }
    return $this->instances[$categoryId][$cacheKey];
}
```

### Deprecated `load()` method

Magento 2 is slowly moving away from the standard CRUD system by dropping the inheritance system and implementing it via composition using the new 2.1 EntityManager you can find details here: [Magento 2.1: using the entity manager](https://magento.stackexchange.com/q/127325/2380)

Also I suggest you read this interesting topic about the deprecated CRUD methods: [Deprecated save and load methods in Abstract Model](https://magento.stackexchange.com/q/114929/2380)

### Why not using the resource model load

The main reason is that if you use the resource model `load` method, you will skip some important part of the loading system that are implemented in the model `load` method, see `Magento\Framework\Model\AbstractModel` :

```
public function load($modelId, $field = null)
{
    $this->_beforeLoad($modelId, $field);
    $this->_getResource()->load($this, $modelId, $field);
    $this->_afterLoad();
    $this->setOrigData();
    $this->_hasDataChanges = false;
    $this->updateStoredData();
    return $this;
}
```

Calling the resource model `load` method directly will have the following impact:

- `_beforeLoad` is not called: thus the model load before events are not dispatched
- `_afterLoad` is not called: thus the model load after events are not dispatched
- the stored data are not updated which can cause various problems (for instance if you call `prepareDataForUpdate` from `Magento\Framework\Model\ResourceModel\Db\AbstractDb` )

Comment: Thanks Raphael, every things you say makes sense and complete my knowledge. But I don't understand why KAndy comments (under his answer) that Marius can use the load() method of his custom module resource model ? It's in [http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/114929/deprecated-save-and-load-methods-in-abstract-model](Deprecated save and load methods in Abstract Model). Any ideas ?

Comment: @NicolasPERNOT basically KAndy explains that the goal is to have SL (Service Layer) for every module and that this is what must be used every time you need to load an entity. I suggest you comment by mentioning him maybe he'll be able to enlighten you as he's a Magento Inc employee I think

Comment: Well, I finally updated my original post. Thank you Raphael for your help.

Comment: I see that at least in Magento 2.2 that important is included into ResourceModel's load, so it's not OK to use ResourceModel methods directly, right?

Comment: Currently, we can safely load Model using the Resource Model `load()` method. Resource Model calls model's methods from own `load()` method: `$model->beforeLoad() { $this->_beforeLoad() }` and `$model->afterLoad() { $this->_afterLoad() }`

Answer (score -2):

I think following statement is not valid now.

```
Why not using the resource model load
```

we can find `Magento\Framework\EntityManager\Observer` folder all events.