# How to load facotry model load best practice?

Tags: magento2, factory, deprecated

```
class Product extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template {

    protected $_productloader;


    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context $context,
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductFactory $_productloader

    ) {
        $this->_productloader = $_productloader;
        parent::__construct($context);
    }

    public function getLoadProduct($id) {
        return $this->_productloader->create()->load($id)
            ;
    }

}
```

I get "Reference Entity Deprecated" on `load()` method so what is the best practice to use `load()` functionality.

Comment: Hi Please refer to this link: http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/142747/best-way-to-load-a-custom-model-in-magento-2

Comment: use Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductRepositoryInterface;  its working for me but i didn't understand getById($id);