# Difference between load() and get() methods

Tags: magento2, methods, object

While going through the Magento code I have been seeing a lot of instances of:

```
$objectName->load($foo)
```

or

```
$objectName->get($foo)
```

and I was wondering, what is the difference between the 'load' and 'get' methods?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**If you have to talk about the load and get at Magento2.**

Then let me clear that

`load()` is *the function of Model class*.

`get()`is *a function of Repository class of service contract*.

Both are used for fetch the data of particular u entity like Product, Cms Page etc  using Primary key.

But load function is deprecated at Magento 2, You have to use the repository class for getting particular table/entity data.

See  detail [When Should We Use a Repository and Factory in Magento 2?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/158081/when-should-we-use-a-repository-and-factory-in-magento-2)

Answer (score 3):

In short, In `Magento2` the best way is to use the service contract `get()` when it's possible, if it's not available you can use `ResourceModel` to save the entities, however the `load()` like `save()`, `delete()` also, are a deprecated methods.

You can see :

[Why use Service contract](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/142756/48355)

[Deprecated save and load methods in Abstract Model](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/114929/deprecated-save-and-load-methods-in-abstract-model/114932#114932)

Answer (score 0):

Get ( ) and Load ( ) are Hibernate Sessions. They provide with different methods to fetch data from the database.  Get ( ) returns the object by fetching it from database Whereas Load  ( ) just returns the reference of an object that might not actually exist. It lodes the data from the database or catch only when you access other properties of the object. Get ( ) helps in retrieving the data that doesn't exist.

The main difference between Get ( ) vs load methods is that get ( ) Lodes the data as soon as it’s called, however, Lodes ( ) supports lazy loading and returns to proxy objects and lodes data as per the requirement.