# Magento2 : Best way to load Customer by customer Id

Tags: magento2, customer, magento-2.1

What is the best way to load Customer by Id? using customer interface or customer factory or another way ?
In most of solutions I found, it is done by directly using `objectManager` (which should be never be used).

Answer (score 38, accepted):

It's always a [better practice to use service contracts.](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/114929/deprecated-save-and-load-methods-in-abstract-model)

In your case I would use `\Magento\Customer\Api\CustomerRepositoryInterface` :

```
protected $_customerRepositoryInterface;
public function __construct(
    ....
    \Magento\Customer\Api\CustomerRepositoryInterface $customerRepositoryInterface,
    ....
) {
    ....
    $this->_customerRepositoryInterface = $customerRepositoryInterface;
}
```

Then in your code you can call:

```
$customerId = 1;
$customer = $this->_customerRepositoryInterface->getById($customerId);
```

Comment: not working ... i have keep it in helper/data.php and call this method in phtml file but not working.

Comment: why its not working in helper class or Model/class?

Comment: It does work, but you can't retrieve information like firstname with `$customer->getData('firstname');` it only works with `$customer->getFirstname();` which is confusing. You can find all methods here: **vendor\magento\module-customer\Api\Data\CustomerInterface.php**