# Magento\Customer\Model\Customer::__construct() must be an instance of Magento\Framework\Model\Context

Tags: magento-2.1, customer, compilation

I have create a module and its working fine when compilation is disabled. Its getting below error when after compilation run.

> PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught TypeError: Argument 1 passed to Magento\Customer\Model\Customer::__construct() must be an instance of Magento\Framework\Model\Context, instance of Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\ObjectManager given,

```
<?php

namespace Supravat\Customer\Helper;

class Customer extends \Magento\Framework\App\Helper\AbstractHelper
{
    protected $customerRepositoryInterface;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\App\Helper\Context $context,
        \Magento\Customer\Api\CustomerRepositoryInterface $customerRepositoryInterface
    ) 
    {
        ...........
        parent::__construct($context);
        $this->customerRepositoryInterface = $customerRepositoryInterface;
    }

    public function getCustomerById() {
        $customer_id  = 1; // 1 is the magento customer id
        $customer = $this->customerRepositoryInterface->getById($customer_id);
        var_dump($customer->getData());
    }
}
```

**Note: Compilation is generates code and dependency injection configuration successfully.**

Comment: If it works fine, why do we need to compile it ?

Comment: after compile its not working. but compilation was successful.

Comment: Yeah, i know. I have the same situation like you before. And after researching, the solution is let it be, don't run di:setup:compile.

Comment: Its should be work with compilation.

Comment: If you cannot fix that bugs, remove the var/di folder and that will be good to go.

Comment: @Supravat I answered below with a working module using your code: https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/188909/36487

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tested on `2.1.6` and `2.1.8` works just fine. I injected the helper into a footer copyright plugin for proof of concept.

#### File Structure

```
app/code/Supravat/
└── Customer
    ├── Helper
    │   └── Customer.php
    ├── Plugin
    │   └── Magento
    │       └── Theme
    │           └── Block
    │               └── Html
    │                   └── Footer.php
    ├── etc
    │   ├── di.xml
    │   └── module.xml
    └── registration.php
```

#### registration.php

```
<?php
    \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
        \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::MODULE,
        'Supravat_Customer',
        __DIR__
    );
```

#### module.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="Supravat_Customer" setup_version="0.0.1"/>
</config>
```

#### di.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Theme\Block\Html\Footer">
        <plugin name="supravat_customer_magento_theme_block_html_footer" type="Supravat\Customer\Plugin\Magento\Theme\Block\Html\Footer"/>
    </type>
</config>
```

#### Customer.php

```
<?php

namespace Supravat\Customer\Helper;

class Customer extends \Magento\Framework\App\Helper\AbstractHelper
{
    protected $customerRepositoryInterface;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\App\Helper\Context $context,
        \Magento\Customer\Api\CustomerRepositoryInterface $customerRepositoryInterface
    ) {
        parent::__construct($context);
        $this->customerRepositoryInterface = $customerRepositoryInterface;
    }

    public function getCustomerById($customerId)
    {
        $customer = $this->customerRepositoryInterface->getById($customerId);
        return var_export($customer->__toArray(), true);
    }
}
```

#### Footer.php

```
<?php

namespace Supravat\Customer\Plugin\Magento\Theme\Block\Html;

use Supravat\Customer\Helper\Customer as Helper;

class Footer
{
    protected $helper;
    public function __construct(Helper $helper)
    {
        $this->helper = $helper;
    }

    public function afterGetCopyright(
        \Magento\Theme\Block\Html\Footer $subject,
        $result
    ) {
        return $this->helper->getCustomerById(1);
    }
}
```

Once all files are in place:

```
./bin/magento --clear-static-content module:enable Supravat_Customer 
./bin/magento setup:upgrade
./bin/magento setup:di:compile
```

Refresh the home page and you should see the customer's information in the footer.

This is obviously just a proof of concept, there isn't any *good* reason why you'd want the customer's information dumped in the footer copyright, but it shows you that it works out of the box.

[image: Footer Copyright plugin]

Answer (score 3):

The **\Magento\Customer\Api\CustomerRepositoryInterface** not injected properly. It should be as shown below:

> Injection patter is wrong.You should inject class as parameter of 
>   __construct().

---

```
<?php

namespace Supravat\Customer\Helper;

class Customer extends \Magento\Framework\App\Helper\AbstractHelper
{
  protected $customerRepositoryInterface;

  public function __construct(
    \Magento\Framework\App\Helper\Context $context,
    \Magento\Customer\Api\CustomerRepositoryInterface $customerRepositoryInterface
) 
{
    ...........
    parent::__construct($context);
    $this->customerRepositoryInterface=$customerRepositoryInterface;

}

public function getCustomerById() {
    $customer_id  = 1; // 1 is the magento customer id
    $customer = $this->customerRepositoryInterface->getById($customer_id);
    var_dump($customer->getData());
}
}
```

Comment: why **CustomerRepositoryInterface** not inject properly? Look  at [Best way to load Customer by Id in Magento 2.1](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/132582/3368)

Comment: That was ok @supravat. Please compare the code given in the link and your helper class. You will find the answer of why

Comment: Did you compile & run this code?

Comment: Did you tried my solution?

Comment: Apology for misplaced of my code. I have update my question. Please check once.

Comment: NP. Did you sure this class is the causing the error?

Comment: Yes. Its working when remove  `var/di`.