# Magento 2: how to enable and disable customer?

Tags: magento2, customer, customer-account

I am looking for code how the customer can be enabled and disabled using customer Id in Magento 2.

When customer is disabled we should not allow customer to login from front end.

I tried setting is_active column as 0 in Database then also i can able to login from frontend.

I am using below code

```
  public function execute(){
     $user = $this->customerFactory->create();
        $userId = $this->getRequest()->getParam('user_id', false);
        $status = 0;
        if($userId):
          $user->load($userId)->setWebsiteId($oldUser->getWebsiteId());      
        endif;
      try {     
            $user->setIsActive($status);
            $user->save();  
         }catch (\Exception $e){
           $this->_messageManager->addError(__('Can\'t save user'));
         }
  }
```

is that can be done pro grammatically?

Comment: there is little big process for doing this batter use free module for ithttps://github.com/amitshree/magento2-account-approval

Comment: It is not correct if we set is_active to 0 in customer_entity table? This module is not my requirement

Comment: it will not work with only set that attribute , you will have to use observer in registration time to check customer approved then login other wise logout it and redirect in same page with not active message same is for login condition you will have to create observer to check customer approved then continue login other wise logout and display message for not logged in like that process you will have to do

Comment: How to check customer is approved or not using customer Id? Because in my controller i get customer id with drop down value enable or disable, Using id i need to implement that functionality,

Comment: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/132577/magento2-best-way-to-load-customer-by-customer-id use this code to load customer by id then get attribute value  $is_active=$customer->getCustomAttribute('is_active');

Comment: is_active is not a custom attribute, its a default attribute, even after getting with
getCustomAttribute also, how to restrict customer by logging in?

Comment: have you checked my answer?

Answer (score 1):

Create customer attribute [Is blocked](https://www.silksoftware.com/magento-module-creator)? (can only edit from admin,setby default NO) http://prntscr.com/n2yn78 , http://prntscr.com/n2yq5r
then use observer event after login check it's value
if it is blocked youcan logged out him and redirect to any page

Use **customer_login** event observer for customer login action

**1) Create events.xml**

> app/code/Vendor/Module/etc/events.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
    <event name="customer_login">
        <observer name="customer_login_observer" instance="Vendor\Module\Observer\CustomerLogin" />
    </event>
</config>
```

**2) Now create observer CustomerLogin.php**

> app/code/Vendor/Module/Observer/CustomerLogin.php

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Module\Observer;

use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;

class CustomerLogin implements ObserverInterface
{
    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\App\ResponseFactory
     */
    private $responseFactory;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\UrlInterface
     */
    private $url;
    private $customerSession;
    private $messageManager;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\App\ResponseFactory $responseFactory,
        \Magento\Framework\UrlInterface $url,
        \Magento\Customer\Model\Session $customerSession,
        \Magento\Framework\Message\ManagerInterface $messageManager
    ) {
        $this->responseFactory = $responseFactory;
        $this->url = $url;
        $this->customerSession= $customerSession;
        $this->messageManager = $messageManager;
    }
    public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
    {
        $customer = $observer->getEvent()->getCustomer();

        if($customer->getIsBlocked()){
            $customerSession->logout();
            $this->messageManager->addErrorMessage(__('You are Blocked'));
            $redirectionUrl = $this->url->getUrl('set-your-redirect-url');
       $this->responseFactory->create()->setRedirect($redirectionUrl)->sendResponse();

            return $this;
        }
    }
}
```