# M2 | How to set default store view of product while creating the product programmatically?

Tags: product, store-view, programmatically, default

I am creating simple product programmatically, but for displaying it on frontend I need to edit product from admin side and set its view from

> All Store Views

to

> Default Store View

Mannually, then it appears on the frontend.

I am creating product as:

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance(); // instance of object manager
        $product = $objectManager->create('\Magento\Catalog\Model\Product');
        $product->setSku('my-sku11'); // Set your sku here
        $product->setName('Sample Simple Product11'); // Name of Product
        $product->setAttributeSetId(4); // Attribute set id
        $product->setStatus(1); // Status on product enabled/ disabled 1/0
        $product->setWeight(10); // weight of product
        $product->setVisibility(4); // visibilty of product (catalog / search / catalog, search / Not visible individually)
        $product->setTaxClassId(0); // Tax class id
        $product->setTypeId('simple'); // type of product (simple/virtual/downloadable/configurable)
        $product->setPrice(100); // price of product
        $product->setStockData(
                                array(
                                    'use_config_manage_stock' => 0,
                                    'manage_stock' => 1,
                                    'is_in_stock' => 1,
                                    'qty' => 99999
                                )
                            );
        $product = $product->save();
```

I have tried this,

```
$product->setStoreId(0); //1,2,3,4
```

but it is not working. How can I achieve it ?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure of this, I just found it but you can give it a try
Add `$product->setWebsiteIds(array(1));`

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance(); // instance of object manager
$product = $objectManager->create('\Magento\Catalog\Model\Product');
$product->setSku('my-sku11'); // Set your sku here
$product->setName('Sample Simple Product11'); // Name of Product
$product->setAttributeSetId(4); // Attribute set id
$product->setStatus(1); // Status on product enabled/ disabled 1/0
$product->setWeight(10); // weight of product
$product->setVisibility(4); // visibilty of product (catalog / search / catalog, search / Not visible individually)
$product->setTaxClassId(0); // Tax class id
$product->setTypeId('simple'); // type of product (simple/virtual/downloadable/configurable)
$product->setPrice(100); // price of product
$product->setStockData(
         array(
              'use_config_manage_stock' => 0,
              'manage_stock' => 1,
              'is_in_stock' => 1,
              'qty' => 99999
              )
             );
$product->setWebsiteIds(array(1));
$product = $product->save();

// Adding Custom option to product
$options = array(
    array(
        "sort_order" => 1,
        "title" => "Option 1",
        "price_type" => "fixed",
        "price" => "10",
        "type" => "field",
        "is_require" => 0
    )
);
foreach ($options as $arrayOption) {
    $product->setHasOptions(1);
    $product->getResource()->save($product);
    $option = $objectManager->create('\Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Option')
        ->setProductId($product->getId())
        ->setStoreId(0)
        ->addData($arrayOption);
    $option->save();
    $product->addOption($option);
}
```

Comment: same..product is creating.. but now with this exception . 1 exception(s):
Exception #0 (Magento\Framework\Validator\Exception): Missed values for option required fields
Invalid option type
Invalid option value

Comment: try updated answer if you get the same error or not

Comment: Exception has gone but store view is same.. i need default store view..

Comment: change `->setStoreId(0)` to this `->setStoreId($product->getStoreId())` and check

Comment: created product but still same scope..

Comment: are you doing it like this way https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/156717/magento-2-create-product-programmatically-with-different-store-view-values

Comment: I am just putting the above code to controller..

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/94003/discussion-between-magefms-and-ajwad-taqvi).

Comment: @AjwadTaqvi `product->setWebsiteIds(array(1));` // change to 0 or other number to check

Comment: Yes it worked, please update the answer so that I will accept it.

Comment: please also upvote question for the help of future readers

Comment: @AjwadTaqvi yeah, I am the one who upvoted it :)