# Using Quote Repository creates a new row after save

Tags: magento2, quote, service-contract

So I am trying to get to grips with Magento 2's new way of handling data using service contracts.

I have the following code:

```
$formData = [
    'quoteId' => '',
    'purchaseOrderNumber' => '',
    'dispatchDate' => '',
    'campaignId' => '',
    'specialInstructions' => ''
];

$formData = $this->getRequest()->getPostValue();

$quoteId = $formData['quoteId'];

$quote = $this->quoteRespository->get($quoteId);

// This shows the correct ID
$this->logger->addDebug(print_r($quote->getId(), 1));

// This shows nothing
$this->logger->addDebug(print_r($quote->getData(), 1));

$dispatchDate = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($formData['dispatchDate']));

$quote->setData([
    'purchase_order_number' => $formData['purchaseOrderNumber'],
    'campaign_id' => $formData['campaignId'],
    'dispatch_date' => $dispatchDate,
    'special_instructions' => $formData['specialInstructions']
]);

// This only contains the info in the setData() call above
$this->logger->addDebug(print_r($quote->getId(), 1));

$this->quoteRespository->save($quote);
```

`$quoteId` is definitely correct. However, if I don't add `entity_id => $quoteId` to the array in `setData()`, it creates a brand new row in the `quote` table! This seems like really strange behaviour.

Can anyone help me out with what is going on and/or what I might be doing wrong?

Using Magento **2.1.5**.

Answer (score 3):

Use **addData** instead of **setData**

```
$quote->addData([
    'purchase_order_number' => $formData['purchaseOrderNumber'],
    'campaign_id' => $formData['campaignId'],
    'dispatch_date' => $dispatchDate,
    'special_instructions' => $formData['specialInstructions']
]);
```