# Save is deprecated when try to create attributes set

Tags: magento2, attribute-set, deprecated

I try to create programmatically some attributes set.

I find this code :

```
    $setup = $this->moduleDataSetup->getConnection();
    $setup->startSetup();
    $categorySetup = $this->categorySetupFactory->create(['setup' => $this->moduleDataSetup]);

    $attributeSet = $this->attributeSetFactory->create();
    $entityTypeId = $categorySetup->getEntityTypeId(\Magento\Catalog\Model\Product::ENTITY);
    $attributeSetId = $categorySetup->getDefaultAttributeSetId($entityTypeId);

    try {

        foreach ($attributeSetNameArray as $attributeSetName) {
            $data = [
                'attribute_set_name' => $attributeSetName,
                'entity_type_id' => $entityTypeId
            ];
            $attributeSet->setData($data);
            $attributeSet->validate();
            $attributeSet->save();
            $attributeSet->initFromSkeleton($attributeSetId);
            $attributeSet->save();
        }
    } catch (\Exception $exception) {
        throw new InputException(__($exception->getMessage()));
    }

    $setup->endSetup();
```

It's work perfectly, but my PhpStorm say that the Method "save" in

> $attributeSet->save();
>
> $attributeSet->initFromSkeleton($attributeSetId)->save();

is deprecated.

Do you know why is deprecated ? How can I fix this ?

Thank you

Comment: it would be easier to help you if your code is complete

Comment: I used this example : https://magecomp.com/blog/how-create-attribute-set-programmatically-assign-attributes-to-it-in-magento-2/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `Magento\Eav\Api\AttributeSetRepositoryInterface;` to handle the **save** attribute
Check this:

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\CustomModule\Setup;

use Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetupFactory;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\InstallDataInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleDataSetupInterface;
use Magento\Catalog\Setup\CategorySetupFactory;
use Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\SetFactory as AttributeSetFactory;
use Magento\Eav\Api\AttributeSetRepositoryInterface;

class InstallData implements InstallDataInterface
{
private $_eavSetupFactory;
private $_attributeSetFactory;
private $_categorySetupFactory;
private $_attribute;

/**
 * InstallData constructor.
 * @param AttributeSetRepositoryInterface $attribute
 * @param EavSetupFactory $eavSetupFactory
 * @param AttributeSetFactory $attributeSetFactory
 * @param CategorySetupFactory $categorySetupFactory
 */
public function __construct(AttributeSetRepositoryInterface $attribute, EavSetupFactory $eavSetupFactory, AttributeSetFactory $attributeSetFactory, CategorySetupFactory $categorySetupFactory )
{
    $this->_eavSetupFactory = $eavSetupFactory;
    $this->_attributeSetFactory = $attributeSetFactory;
    $this->_categorySetupFactory = $categorySetupFactory;
    $this->_attribute = $attribute;
}

/**
 * @param ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup
 * @param ModuleContextInterface $context
 * @throws \Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException
 */
public function install(ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context)
{
    $setup->startSetup();

    $categorySetup = $this->_categorySetupFactory->create(['setup' => $setup]);

    $attributeSet = $this->_attributeSetFactory->create();
    $entityTypeId = $categorySetup->getEntityTypeId(\Magento\Catalog\Model\Product::ENTITY);
    $attributeSetId = $categorySetup->getDefaultAttributeSetId($entityTypeId);
    $data = [
        'attribute_set_name' => 'YOUR_ATTRIBUTE_SET_NAME',
        'entity_type_id' => $entityTypeId,
        'sort_order' => 200,
    ];

    try{

        $attributeSet->setData($data);
        $attributeSet->validate();
        $this->_attribute->save($attributeSet);

        $attributeSet->initFromSkeleton($attributeSetId);
        $this->_attribute->save($attributeSet);

    } catch (\Exception $exception) {
        throw new InputException(__($exception->getMessage()));
    }


    // CREATE PRODUCT ATTRIBUTE
    $eavSetup = $this->_eavSetupFactory->create(['setup' => $setup]);

    $eavSetup->addAttribute(
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product::ENTITY,
        'attribute_id',
        [
            'type' => 'varchar',
            'label' => 'YOUR ATTRIBUTE LABEL',
            'backend' => '',
            'input' => 'text',
            'wysiwyg_enabled'   => false,
            'source' => '',
            'required' => false,
            'sort_order' => 5,
            'global' => \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Eav\Attribute::SCOPE_STORE,
            'used_in_product_listing' => true,
            'visible_on_front' => true,
            'attribute_set_id' => 'TESTING ATTRIBUTE',
        ]
    );

    $setup->endSetup();
}
}
```

Comment: When I try your code, I get : Fatal error: Class Magento\Eav\Model\ResourceModel\Attribute\Interceptor contains 2 abstract methods and must therefore be declared abstract or implement the remaining methods (Magento\Eav\Model\ResourceModel\Attribute::_getEavWebsiteTable, Magento\Eav\Model\ResourceModel\Attribute::_getFormAttributeTable) in /var/www/magento/generated/code/Magento/Eav/Model/ResourceModel/Attribute/Interceptor.php on line 7. I'm not sure to understand why I need to implement theses functions because I not extends this class

Comment: I have updated the answer please check

Comment: Work perfectly ! Thank you ! Can you just explain me why we use AttributeSetRepositoryInterface instead of Attribute ?

Comment: can't really explain it but you can check it from the documentation https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/extension-dev-guide/service-contracts/service-contracts.html#what-is-msc 
magento introduces and recommends to use module service contract to mitigate some issues with custom extension dependencies

Answer (score 1):

Magento 2 repo contains load and save methods from `Magento\Framework\Model\AbstractModel` that are deprecated. If you follow the guidelines that the core module does, you may face a problem: it is necessary to use something instead of them or extend something else. One of the possible most obvious solution is to use Module Service Contract – [ProductRepositoryInterface](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.2-develop/app/code/Magento/Catalog/Api/ProductRepositoryInterface.php) for products. Alternatively, you can save entities via ResourceModel if Module Service Contract is unavailable.

ProductRepositoryInterface Example and Usage Reference link:

1. https://hotexamples.com/examples/magento.catalog.api/ProductRepositoryInterface/-/php-productrepositoryinterface-class-examples.html
2. https://mage2.pro/t/topic/1297

**I hope this will help**

Comment: Thank you for your explanation. But can you please show me some example ? I'm not sure to really understand how to use ProductRepositoryInterface..

Answer (score 1):

Yes of course, as `save()`, `delete()`, `load()` are **deprecated** now, you have to use a `service contract` or `resourceModel`

You can read [this](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/114929/deprecated-save-and-load-methods-in-abstract-model).

Comment: Can you please share an ewample of service contract  or resourceModel ? I'm not sur to understand how to apply this in my code